# error class interface or enum expected - Adding 2 numbers from Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

This is code my to add 2 numbers in Android. Please help me.

```
public void    onButtonclick(View v) {
    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
    int sum = num1 + num2;
    t1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
}
```

Comment: Can you give some more detail on what error you get, and what you actually want to achieve

Comment: Probably you have missed a class declaration or an extra brace({) somewhere added. Double-check your code.

Comment: show your logcat here

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
t1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
```

With

```
t1.setText(""+sum);
```

Or Bettersolution

*`t1.setText(String.valueOf(sum));`*